# Can I embed PowerBI report in Power Apps in the app-owns-data fashion?

Tags: powerbi, powerapps, powerbi-embedded

I have a .NET web application where I am using the app-owns data approach to embed PowerBI reports to allow users registered in the Azure AD of my organization to view and use the reports, without them needing a PowerBI license.

Is there a way to do the same thing in Power Apps ?